# Проверка на удаления

Tags: php

Как реализовать проверку на удаления записи из базы. "Вы действительно хотите удалить запись?" да или нет?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А можно ещё проще:
    <a href="example.com/some/url" onclick="return confirm('Уверены?');">Link</a>

Answer (score 1):

Да или Нет - это не PHP, это HTML. А вот PHP будет, когда обработчик будет принимать параметры.

```
<a href="/delete/?del=yes">Да</a>
<a href="/delete/?del=no">Нет</a>
```

Файл /delete/index.php

```
if ($del == 'yes') {
    удаляем запись из БД
} else {
    не удаляем
}
```

Comment: if(isset($_GET['del'] && $_GET['del']=='yes')

Comment: @FLK думаете стоит напоминать как получать переменные? Может быть у автора вообще register_global = on :)

Comment: @Angelina_Jo думаю стоит, судя по качеству вопроса